# How to set TimerTrigger value programmatically?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I'm writing webjob to automate sending email every month , whose day will be fixed by a setting. How to set scheduleExpression of TimerTrigger("0 0 0 */6 * *", RunOnStartup = true) programmatically?

This 6th of every month in above scheduleExpression will be variable, set using a setting. How to set it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the CRON expression `"0 0 0 */6 * *"` as a variable in the TimerTrigger attribute.

workaround 1: Please add a settings.job to the project and in visual studio,set its property `"copy to output directory"` to `"copy always"`, then add your cron expression like `{"schedule": "*/15 * * * * *"}`

workaround 2: The 2nd one may not meet your need. Just take a look. Customize your own schedule based on daily or weekly, please refer to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitagarwal/2018/01/01/custom-schedule-for-azure-web-job-timer-triggers/)

Comment: I tried:                                                                 
          public class CustomScheduleMonthly : TimerSchedule
          {            
            public string scheduleExpression { get; set; }
            public CustomScheduleMonthly()
            {                
                var setting = getSetting();
                if (setting.Enabled == true)
                {
                    int day = setting.Day;                    
                    this.scheduleExpression = $"0 0 0 {day} * *";                    
                }
              }

Comment: and for timertrigger:                                                                                        
    public void Handle([TimerTrigger(typeof(CustomScheduleMonthly), 
    RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, TextWriter log)

Comment: if it is 6th day of every month, should I pass {day} or 0/{day} ?

Comment: just pass {day}